# Convert each individual cell in a sprite image from 64x64 to 60x60?

Tags: gimp, image-sprite

I have a sprite that is a single PNG image with each cell being 64x64 pixels. Is there a way in GIMP 2 to to somehow shave off the border of each cell so that it will become a PNG image that holds 60x60 pixel cells?

Is there also a way to include a 1px black border in each of the 60x60 cell as well?

Comment: Shaving the border off an image is called "cropping". There's a crop tool in GIMP.

Comment: Yeah, but the sprite image is a single PNG file. Within that file holds many individual square images (cells). How would you split these cells within that file into individual 64x64 images, then 'crop' them to 60x60, then save them again into a single PNG file?

Comment: There's probably no way to automate that in GIMP if that's what you are asking. It would be a tedious manual edit: selecting a 60 x 60 portion of each image, and copying and pasting them and repositioning in a new document.

Comment: @BillyKerr: can GIMP remove entire columns and rows from images? (It'd still be manual work but much less than all that copy-and-pasting.)

Comment: With a script maybe. xenoid seems to have given you a solution perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

With the [`ofn-layer-tiles` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/):

- Starting with:

[image]

- `Layer>Tiles>Split tiles (by width and eight)`

  - Enter your with and jeight: (64, 64)
  - `Position: Superimpose`
- Your image will be transformed into a 64x64 stack of layers
- Crop that image to remove the sides that you don't want
- Reconstruct the sprite sheet with`Layer>Tiles>Join tiles`

  - `Row/Columns: Parse layer names`
  - `Final image: Flatten to single layer`

[image]

- `Filter>Render>Pattern>Grid` to add a border to your cells (here: `offsets=(-1,-1)` and `widths=(2,2)`)

[image]